# Google Sheet - detecting the user editing the sheet "onEdit"

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have been struggling with a very basic question since last couple of days, here is what I am trying to achieve.
I have a google sheet which is shared with a team. Each team member will add one or more rows in the sheet. There is column within the sheet which should log the email id of the person making the changes. This is how I tried to achieve this-

- I created a simple "onEdit" trigger but realized that this trigger is not allowed to access the editors identity if he is not the owner.
- I moved the entire code into a separate script and published it as webapp but still the "Session.getActiveUser()" returns blank and "Session.getEffectiveUser()" returns sheet owner's email.
- I created a custom menu and asked the users to click on that one before proceeding, and within the action of custom menu I first forced user to authenticate by using 
  *SpreadsheetApp.openById(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId());tried* then tried following things-
- I created a executable "onEdit" trigger via code for each user. This worked a couple of times but when I logged-in with another user
  the behavior was very unpredictable and I could not conclude what is
  happening here. (sometimes getting user's email and sometime's
  owners)

  I fetch the user email when he tries to authenticate and saved it in userProperties. I then tried to fetch it in "onEdit" but again
  the behavior is not consistent when I switch the user.
- I also tried an approach which was mentioned on another thread. But again that is not working. here is the code for that one:

---

```
  function getUserEmail() {
  var protection=SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange("B2").protect();
  var userEmail='';
  Session.getEffectiveUser();
  protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
  var editors=protection.getEditors();
  var user1=editors.pop().toString()
  if(editors.length==1){
    var owner=SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getOwner().getEmail();
    if(owner==user1){
      userEmail=editors.pop().toString()
    }else{
      userEmail = user1
    }
  }else{
    userEmail = user1
  }
  protection.remove();
  return userEmail;
}
```

---

I am really running out of the ideas here and loosing my hope, any suggestion is highly appreciated.

> Please Note - I can force user to authenticate or press on a menu item once during a session but after that it should get the email id automatically while editing anything.

Thanks.

Comment: You stated that one thing you tried was very unpredictable.  So, I'm assuming that the code ran, and got a user email, but it wasn't always the correct email.  If you have many users, and there are moments when multiple users are adding data in rapid succession, you will probably have a problem.  If a subsequent instance of the same function begins to run before the first instance of the function has completed, what might happen is that variable values get changed to the second instance values before the first instance of the function has completed.  You must lock the code with Lock Service.

Comment: Since you are able to get the email address for some users you are using a G Suite account. Is your spreadsheet shared only with users of the same organización?

Comment: No, I am not on G Suit and that's the problem, otherwise onEdit would be able able to access email id using activeuser ()

Comment: I am still looking for a solution to this problem, if someone can help. Thanks